# Running react and node in a single port using Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I am trying to run docker for my sample project where in the container I need a single port to run, But the build of react code will serve as the index.html, I have the below folder structure.

In index.js file I have tried to add the static path, What am I doing wrong here? I have commented it..

I have tried this much.

```
sampleapp
   client
     // using cra (create react app) files
     src
     public
     ...
   server
     index.js
   Dockerfile
```

// app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    response: null
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.dataFetching()
  }

  dataFetching = async () => {
    const resjson = await fetch('/api/data');
    const res = await resjson.json();
    this.setState({
      response: res.data
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
        this.state.response ? this.state.response : null
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

// package.json --client

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

// index.js -- server

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,  'build')));

// app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
//     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'build', 'index.html'));
// });

app.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    res.send({data: "Success"})
})

app.listen(4000);
```

// Dockerfile - sampleapp

```
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine

COPY . /var/app

WORKDIR /var/app/client
RUN npm install --no-cache && npm run build && npm install -g serve


WORKDIR /var/app/server
RUN npm install --no-cache


EXPOSE 4000
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: why using two `EXPOSE`? Better use `Isomorphic` instead.

Comment: how to do that one

Comment: i am able to run the app without docker, but when using docker not working as expected .

Comment: You need to add `CMD` so that container can use it to start

Comment: for the `EXPOSE` you can change it to `EXPOSE 3000 4000`

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS first remove `EXPOSE 3000` first, then when you run your docker do like `docker run -d your-image-name -p 4000:4000`

Comment: getting the below error "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-p\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
"

Comment: i am able to run the docker but when i hit localhost:5000 its a empty page , but if i hit localhost:5000/api/data i am getting the response as success. Why i am getting blank page, it should show the UI ?? any help appreciated

Comment: Got it, finally. Working both react and node in  a single port. Will post the detailed answer . Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Dockerfile` you can change it to the following:

```
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine

COPY . /var/app

WORKDIR /var/app/client
RUN npm install --no-cache && npm run build && npm install -g serve


WORKDIR /var/app/server
RUN npm install --no-cache

EXPOSE 4000 

CMD [ "npm", "start", "index.js" ]
```

For `index.js` (server), you can change it to the following:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    res.send({data: "Success"})
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,  '..', 'client', 'build')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');
```

1. React will be served as a static file through nodeJS
2. `index.js` needs to be binded to `0.0.0.0` so you can connect to it from outside the container.